# using characterAtIndex on a decimal point in objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to do some stuff with `characterAtIndex` and I'm stumped.  `if ([myString characterAtIndex:0]==0)` works fine, if I'm looking for the number zero--but if I'm looking for a decimal point, `if ([myString characterAtIndex:0]==.)` just gives me an error.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check again. `[myString characterAtIndex:0] == 0` will *compile*, but it won't do what you expect. That condition tests if the first character of your string is the character with the ASCII value of 0, which *isn't* the numeral 0: it's the NUL character.

`-characterAtIndex:` returns a value that you can compare with a character literal, which is a character enclosed in single quotes: `'0'` or `'.'`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something got lost in translation, but looking at your current question, I think this is what the solution would look like (compiles and executes as expected for me):

```
if([myString characterAtIndex:0] == '.') {
  // ...
}
```

Note that you must use single-quotes (apostrophe), as these are c-style char items (technically ints) and not c-style strings (which would use double-quotes, and technically be an array/pointer)

Answer (score 2):

characterAtIndex returns a unichar character, so use '.' instead.

ie:  `if ([myString characterAtIndex:0]=='.')`